# How can I normalize and interpolate missing values in a timeseries in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, arrays, time-series

Let's assume I have a Ruby array with arrays of time/value pairs, like:

```
[
  # about 9:00 AM on consecutive days
  [<DateTime: 2014-05-15T09:00:00Z>, 56],
  [<DateTime: 2014-05-16T09:06:00Z>, 57],
    # ... missing data for May 17th, 2014
    # ... missing data for May 18th, 2014
  [<DateTime: 2014-05-19T08:57:00Z>, 61],
  # ...
]
```

Notice that (1) the values aren't collected at the same time each day, and (2) some of the values are missing.

I want to normalize the data by:

1. resampling it so that they're equally spaced in time and
2. interpolating any missing values.

What's the right way to programmatically do that?

### Update 1

> How do you want to interpolate? In your example [58, 59], [58, 60] and [59, 60] would be equally plausible.

The expected value will depend on the interpolation strategy that gets used (e.g., linear, quadratic, etc.), so I can't provide an exact answer.

I'm willing to accept any interpolation strategy that predicts the original, actual data points with minimal error (e.g. < 0.1%). I'm willing to accept any normalization strategy that results in the timeseries observations being equally spaced.

Comment: Could you post the expected output?

Comment: How do you want to interpolate? In your example [58, 59], [58, 60] and [59, 60] would be equally plausible.

Comment: Looking at the date range it seems like on weekends the data is not collected. So taking the weekdays as your timeframe might solve your (1- equally spaced in time reqmnt)?

Comment: {@Stefan, @MichaelKohl}: I've updated the question body to reflect my answer to your question.  @uDaY: Unfortunately, that's just a coincidence (I made up this data). The real data is several years long with measurements that are roughly daily (but sometimes occur more than once per day, and sometimes go without data for weeks at a time).

Comment: The first thing I'd do is plot it, to see if there are any obvious patterns/anomalies (e.g., outliers) and whether a least-square fit may be called for. Can you post a link to the data (e.g., on GitHub)?

Comment: Are there any other constraints on the data? If you have some model of what the time curve should be, you can use existing data to fit to that curve. If not, I would use a local fit (ie. spline answer below ) to interpolate across gaps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use spline interpolation. Here's an example using the [Spliner gem](https://github.com/tallakt/spliner):

```
require 'date'
require 'spliner'

arr = [
  [DateTime.new(2014,5,15,9), 56],
  [DateTime.new(2014,5,16,9,6), 57],
  [DateTime.new(2014,5,19,8,57), 61]
]

spline = Spliner::Spliner.new(arr.to_h, extrapolate: '10%')

(DateTime.new(2014,5,15,9)..DateTime.new(2014,5,19,9)).each do |date|
  puts "#{date}: #{spline[date]}"
end
```

Output:

```
2014-05-15T09:00:00+00:00: 56.0                 # exact value
2014-05-16T09:00:00+00:00: 56.995496729398646   # interpolated value
2014-05-17T09:00:00+00:00: 58.18937752978536    # interpolated value
2014-05-18T09:00:00+00:00: 59.55365781173006    # interpolated value
2014-05-19T09:00:00+00:00: 61.0030489943531     # extrapolated value
```

Answer (score 1):

`a` is the first and `b` is the last element of your current array. This solution is like 98% there, the last thing you have to do is add/remove a couple of minutes from the last date to make it 9am (so correcting for the difference between `days` and `days.round`).

```
days = b.first - a.first
per_day = (b.last - a.last) / days
days.round.times.map.with_index(1).inject([a]) do |arr,(_,i)| 
  arr << [a.first + i, (a.last + i * per_days).to_f]
  arr
end
#=> [[#<DateTime: 2014-05-15T09:00:00+00:00 ((2456793j,32400s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>, 56], 
     [#<DateTime: 2014-05-16T09:00:00+00:00 ((2456794j,32400s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>, 57.250651380927565], 
     [#<DateTime: 2014-05-17T09:00:00+00:00 ((2456795j,32400s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>, 58.501302761855136], 
     [#<DateTime: 2014-05-18T09:00:00+00:00 ((2456796j,32400s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>, 59.7519541427827], 
     [#<DateTime: 2014-05-19T09:00:00+00:00 ((2456797j,32400s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>, 61.002605523710265]]
```